# My .exe download file disappears automatically as soon as downloaded gets completed

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to download a application that is required for giving online exams. The problem is that as soon as the .exe file gets downloaded, it disappears. 
Moreover, I'm astonished to see that even if I download the .zip file for the same application, on extraction it again disappears.

Comment: Is it being quarantined or deleted because it matches a virus signature?

Comment: is that possible even when I've disabled virus and thread protection?. If yes, how to stop that from happening.

Comment: You haven't disabled all security software.

Comment: I've disabled the widows protection. I don't have any other installed

Comment: Can you provide a link to the download? If you can't, what happens if you use a PowerShell cmdlet to download the file, e.g. From a PowerShell command prompt run: `wget https://whatevertheurlis.com/files/file.exe -outfile C:\file.exe` or maybe try: `wget https://whatevertheurlis.com/files/file.exe -outfile C:\file.zzz`.  The zzz extension might allow the file to be downloaded?  If you can get the file, you could even submit it to VirusTotal, see what that has to say.  Seems odd they would give you something that is malicious but it could be a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different reasons this may be happening.  Assuming this exe is a safe file you can try get to an answer by process of elimination trying these solutions.

Make sure you are running as administrator

Add (temporarily) *.exe to Windows Defender malware exception list

Use a different browser.

Use safe mode with networking

Use a different archiver such as WinRAR (make sure 'prohibited file types' is unchecked in program settings)